OpenStreetMap не оображается на MapView. Android Studio
AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

build.gradle
implementation libs.osmdroid.android.v6118

activity_main.xml
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="366dp"
    android:layout_height="589dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Mainactivity.java
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, 
insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = 
insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, 
systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}

при запуске приложения я не вижу содержимого карты в окне MapView.  Но видна сетка карты на белом фоне и кнопки зума на ней. В чем может быть дело?
